# Process doesn`t end in java, not passing control ahead

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am trying to invoke a command prompt and logging in some credentials into it. For this I am taking following approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // init shell

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd");
    Scanner scanner = null;
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {

        scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your MS ID : ");
        String user = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter your MS Password : ");
        String pass = scanner.nextLine();

        Process p = builder.start();
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));

        writer.write("oc logout");
        writer.newLine();
        writer.flush();

        writer.write("oc login <private-url>");
        writer.newLine();
        writer.flush();

        writer.write(user);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.flush();

        writer.write(pass);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.flush();



//Writing this will end the process after login is done
//          writer.write("exit");
//          writer.newLine();
//          writer.flush();

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
                    ;
                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
        });
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } 
    finally {
        scanner.close();
    }


}
```

But when I run the program, it just does not end. Eclipse and running by cmd always need to explicitly exit the program. Maybe I am missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated. It just works for the desired thing but does not exit and I need to integrate in my program and not able to do so.

Comment: Why do you need a thread? And, when does it exit?

Comment: That`s for getting cmd outputs to console, doing so in the main thread just gives the first output and not after I have passed inputs to console. I haven`t made it exit as doing so is not putting output to console.

Comment: @MohitSharma no need to flush after every write statement. Close writer (will be flushed upon closing)

Comment: Sure, will take care of that too :)

Comment: Removing flush statement also breaks it and it doesn`t end, just tried it.

Answer (score 0):

**You don't close the `writer`!**

Your loop in the runnable task asks the reader whether it has more input:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { ... }
```

This is always the case unless the `writer` in the main thread is closed. So for a quick solution put a simple `writer.close()` after the last writing action.

The better solution is to use the *[try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)*, introduced with Java 7. You should open your readers, writers, scanners, etc. as following:

```
try (Scanner scanner = ...) { ... }
try {Reader reader = ...) { ... }
try {Writer writer = ...) { ... }
```

These statements will handle the closing [automatically](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) for you. And as a side effect, it will make your code much more readable.

*Warning*: Closing a `Scanner` which is connected with `System.in` also closes the standard input, so that after that point no input can be read anymore. If that is not appropriate in your part of the code, then do not close the scanner.

Comment: I tried using try-with resource, but it still doesn`t end the process, however when I tried putting the "exit" command in writer, it exits. Any idea what else is needed to be taken care of. Post updated with new code.

Comment: "I tried using try-with resource, but it still doesn't end the process" => That can't be. If you have a `try (BufferedWriter writer = ...) { ... }` statement in your code, it will definitively end the process. I tested it!